# Testing Logistic Regression with single variable does not return right output

Tags: r, logistic-regression, predict

this is a sample of the dataset with 500 records that I'm using to build the model. I want to predict if people with certain age and salary bought the car or not:

```
# Age  EstimatedSalary  Purchased
# 23             20000          0
# 47             32000          1
# 31             25000          0
# 19             19000          0
# 25             33000          0
# 38             65000          1
# 48             21000          0
```

Here is the code:

```
#Logistic Regression 

# importing the dataset and choosing Age and Salary column
dataset <- read.csv('Car_Ads.csv')
dataset <- dataset[, 3:5]

#split dataset into train and test
library(caTools)
set.seed(123)
split <- sample.split(dataset$Purchased, SplitRatio=0.75)
training_set <- subset(dataset, split == TRUE)
test_set <- subset(dataset, split == FALSE)

#feature scaling for both columns
training_set[, 1:2] <- scale(training_set[, 1:2])
test_set[, 1:2] <- scale(test_set[, 1:2])

#fitting logistic regression to dataset
classifier <- glm(formula=Purchased ~ ., family=binomial, data=training_set)

#predicting the test set results
prob_pred <- predict(classifier, type='response', newdata=test_set[-3])
y_pred <- ifelse(prob_pred > 0.5, 1, 0)
```

The code is working fine because `y_pred` is a array of 0 and 1 which I can compare with `test_set` and I can create confusion matrix with them. then I wanted to test this model with a single value so I added this lines of codes:

```
#predict by single value
var <- data.frame(Age=20, EstimatedSalary=40000)
var1 <- predict(classifier, type='response', newdata=var)
var2 <- ifelse(var1 > 0.5, 1, 0)
print(var2)
```

It isn't logically working. no matter how I change Age and Salary, It always return:

```
print(var2)
# 1 
# 1
```

why this happen and how can I fix this?

**Update:**
printing each variable (console output in RStudio):

```
#predict by single value
var <- data.frame(Age=20, EstimatedSalary=40000)
print(var)
#   Age EstimatedSalary
# 1  20           40000
var1 <- predict(classifier, type='response', newdata=var)
print(var1)
# 1 
# 1 
var2 <- ifelse(var1 > 0.5, 1, 0)
print(var2)
# 1 
# 1
```

actually I implemented this in python too and every time I change my `var` I get different outputs of 0 and 1. this always return 1.

as @Edward mentioned i scaled my `var`. it turns into `NaN` and I get error:

```
    > var=scale(var) 
    > var
         Age EstimatedSalary
    [1,] NaN             NaN
```

Error :'data' must be a data.frame, not a matrix or an array

**Update 2:**
I scaled my data. now it return different combination of 0 0 , 0 1 , 1 0, 1 1 based on value of Age and Salary. now the problem is the same as the beginning that it does not return one single value of 0 or 1 because a customer did purchase the car or did not. in python my output is either 0 or 1.output must be a single value. I didn't have this problem with Regression models. all my classification models have this logical error. this is the code I used for scaling:

```
  # importing dataset
  dataset=read.csv('Social_Network_Ads.csv')
  dataset=dataset[,3:5]
  mean_df1=mean(dataset[,1])
  sd_df1=sd(dataset[,1])
  mean_df2=mean(dataset[,2])
  sd_df2=sd(dataset[,2])

  var=data.frame(Age=20,EstimatedSalary=30000)
  var[1,1]=(var[1,1] - mean_df1) / sd_df1
  var[1,2]=(var[1,2] - mean_df2) / sd_df2

  output:
  print (var)
          Age          EstimatedSalary
        1 -1.684175       -1.165573
```

Comment: I cannot see any wrong with the value. Check `var1` to see if its value is greater than 0.5.

Comment: Try various combinations of `Age` and `EstimatedSalary` and show the output or var1. We can't really help without a sample of the data. For those 3 records, I get 0 for the predicted value.

Comment: @Edward I mentioned in my question that I used various single values (I mean for example 31,3000 27,8000 12,10000) and it always re turn 1 1 which means `var1` is always 1 1.  what is the sample of data you are talking about? I mentioned that data is dataset of 500 records and I showed 3 records. what exactly should I add to my question?

Comment: If you scale your predictors, then you may have to scale the variables in `newdata` as well. Do you do that in Python?

Comment: @Edward i updated my question. it seems that scale can not use variance to scale because it is just a single record.

Comment: No, you need to convert Age 20 and Salary 40000 into the equivalent scaled versions based on the training or test datasets (not sure which one). Ex, if the mean age is 20, then the scaled value is 0.

Comment: Looks like you have fixed the problem now. `var2` now returns 0 or 1, depending on your input.

Comment: @Edward no. it returns a binary of 0 and 1. not a single 0 or 1.